# Using declare in SQL query with a join in to get date time between for yesterday

Tags: sql, join, declare, sap-mii

I am trying to use this query to bring back yesterdays data,
---- represents columns/tables

```
DECLARE @today date = GETDATE()

SELECT * 
FROM ------
LEFT JOIN -----
ON ------ = ----
WHERE ------.DATE_TIME   >= @today
AND -----.DATE_TIME   <  DATEADD(DAY, -1, @today)
```

I have used this DECLARE STATEMENT before and it worked but never with a join.

I am getting this error back [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4RRl.png)

Error text:

> incorrect syntax near "DECLARE": line 1 col 1 (at pos 1) OpenSQLExceptionCategories: [NON_TRANSIENT, SYNTAX_ERROR]

Yesterdays data, is there another way of doing this?

Comment: (1) Don't paste images when pasting text is better (I added the error text for you), and (2) Add your RDBMS as a tag for this question.

Comment: Also, why do you need the `declare` statement at all? Why can't you just use `GETDATE()` within the query itself?

Comment: RDBMS? Sorry I'm a newbie

Comment: Yes, what Relational Database Management System are you using? Oracle? Microsoft SQL Server? MySQL?  Add a tag to your question, because they don't all use the same syntax, so a reliable answer might depend on that.

Comment: My version (SAP MII) SQL transaction doesn't have that function or I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the syntax issues, it looks like the boundaries were backwards. No value will ever be both after today and before yesterday.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ------
LEFT JOIN -----
    ON ------ = ----
WHERE ------.DATE_TIME >= DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    AND -----.DATE_TIME < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

The above is correct for a Microsoft SQL Server backend. The error message also indicates SAP is talking to... something else. In order to write this correctly you need to know what backend database type you're using behind SAP.

After some digging, I finally found [this page](https://answers.sap.com/questions/9383777/recommended-database-for-sap-mii.html), which suggests [`MaxDB`](https://maxdb.sap.com/) as a possibility. If that is correct, [the documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_NETWEAVER_DBOS/798ce92dc90c47aa8dd1092c185c45df/44e3e0354c836c2fe10000000a114a6b.html?q=subdate) suggests the code should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ------
LEFT JOIN -----
    ON ------ = ----
WHERE ------.DATE_TIME >=  subdate(date(now()),1)
    AND -----.DATE_TIME <  date(now())
```